# File permissions on IIS windows server for Joomla

Tags: iis, joomla, file-permissions, windows-server

I installed Joomla 3 on the IIS windows server 2016.  My Joomla files located in the `inetpub/wwwroot` folder.

When I upload an image from Joomla `Media Manager`, it uploads, **but doesn't show**.

Then when I go to `wwwroot` properties/security tab and change `IIS_IUSRS` permissions checkboxes and apply, It works on the file's permissions and the problem is solved and image shows.

But When I upload a new image, I have the same problem again and the image doesn't show again!

How can I do it? How can I set Joomla or Windows permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I change the permissions on "`upload_tmp_dir`" (path in `php.ini` file) folder to match my web app folder permissions. I add `IIS_IURS` to this folder and set permissions.